# Compass css_parser ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems

I've just began installing SASS and COMPASS. The next step was to install the CSS_PARSER. This was pretty easy step but... I inserted as told by their [website](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass). Insert this into the terminal:

```
sudo gem install css_parser
```

After some seconds it begins to install but I get this alert and I'm stuck:

```
sudo gem install compass
Successfully installed compass-0.12.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for compass-0.12.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for compass-0.12.2...
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ DanielRamirez$ sudo gem install css_parser
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing css_parser:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

What does this mean and how do I follow?

Comment: The css_parser gem isn't actually required for Compass or Sass.  Are you installing it just because the tutorial suggests it and doesn't clarify that it is purely optional or because you actually want the features provided by the gem?

Comment: exactly... the toturial says so... the beginning of SASS is quite painfull. I've seen it work and its perfect! I'm using sublime text 2 and now its working or at least installed. Now I get the problem that if I change something of for example screen.scss does not do any changes at screen.css. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  I'm afraid I can't help you with that, since I only use Sass/Compass via command line.